# Bridged routing with KVM and independent IP addresses

Tags: linux, networking, debian, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have a dedicated Server (at Hetzner), with Debian Jessie and und KVM for virtualization. For the two Virtual Machines I have two additional IP addresses (with extra MAC addresses), which are not part of a subnet (or related to the main IP).

```
Main IP: WW.XX.YY.179
Additional IP 1: AA.BB.CC.DD
Additional IP 2: EE.FF.GG.HH
```

I want to use a bridged setup to bring my VMs to the internet and make them available from outside. And basically I used the documentation from the [Hetzner wiki](https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/KVM_mit_Nutzung_aller_IPs_-_the_easy_way/en) to achieve this.

I can ping (ssh) from server to virtual machines using the external IPs (WW.XX.YY.179, AA.BB.CC.DD, EE.FF.GG.HH) but I cannot reach the outside internet from the VMs nor reach the VMs from outside.

What is the missing piece here? I'd appreciate your kind help! Thanks a lot!
Cheers!

--

On the **server** I use the following configuration in /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto  eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address   WW.XX.YY.179
  netmask   255.255.255.224
  gateway   WW.XX.YY.160
  up route add -net WW.XX.YY.179 netmask 255.255.255.224 gw WW.XX.YY.160 eth0

auto  br0
iface br0 inet static
 address   WW.XX.YY.179
 netmask   255.255.255.255
 bridge_ports none
 bridge_stp off
 bridge_fd 0
 bridge_maxwait 0
 up route add -host AA.BB.CC.DD  dev br0
 up route add -host EE.FF.GG.HH dev br0
```

And the **client** uses the following network configuration:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address AA.BB.CC.DD
    netmask 255.255.255.255
    gateway WW.XX.YY.160
    pointopoint WW.XX.YY.179
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

--

Here are some outputs from the commands executed on the **server**:

```
root@server ~ # ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:50:56:00:3c:ae  
          inet addr:WW.XX.YY.179  Bcast:WW.XX.YY.179  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::2020:30ff:fe08:631f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:188 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:193 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:25958 (25.3 KiB)  TX bytes:22480 (21.9 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:62:6d:99:89:b1  
          inet addr:WW.XX.YY.179  Bcast:WW.XX.YY.BB  Mask:255.255.255.224
          inet6 addr: fe80::8f51:6dff:fe88:92b1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:825 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:702 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:90106 (87.9 KiB)  TX bytes:189776 (185.3 KiB)

*(omitted lo here...)*


vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:50:56:00:3c:af  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc50:56ff:fe00:3caf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:120 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:182 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:15247 (14.8 KiB)  TX bytes:23643 (23.0 KiB)

vnet1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:50:56:00:3c:ae  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc50:56ff:fe00:3cae/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:40 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:86 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:5351 (5.2 KiB)  TX bytes:16307 (15.9 KiB)

root@server ~ # brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.fe5056003cae   no      vnet0
                            vnet1

root@server ~ # brctl showmacs br0
port no mac addr        is local?   ageing timer
  1 00:50:56:00:3c:af   no        58.00
  3 fe:50:56:00:3c:ae   yes        0.00
  1 fe:50:56:00:3c:af   yes        0.00


root@server ~ # ip route
default via WW.XX.YY.161 dev eth0 
WW.XX.YY.160/27 via WW.XX.YY.161 dev eth0 
WW.XX.YY.160/27 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src WW.XX.YY.179 
AA.BB.CC.DD dev br0  scope link 
EE.FF.GG.HH dev br0  scope link

root@server ~ # ping AA.BB.CC.DD
PING AA.BB.CC.DD (AA.BB.CC.DD) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from AA.BB.CC.DD: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.581 ms
*.... \o/*

root@server ~ # for file in `find /proc/ -iname send_redirects`; do echo $file; cat $file; done
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/send_redirects
0
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/br0/send_redirects
0
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/default/send_redirects
0
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/send_redirects
0
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/lo/send_redirects
0
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/vnet0/send_redirects
0
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/vnet2/send_redirects
0
```

--

Here are some outputs from the commands executed on the **virtual machine**:

```
root@vm1 ~ # ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:00:3c:af  
          inet addr:AA.BB.CC.DD  Bcast:AA.BB.CC.DD  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe00:3caf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:192 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:125 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:24463 (23.8 KiB)  TX bytes:15857 (15.4 KiB)

*(omitted lo here...)*


root@vm1 ~ # ip route
WW.XX.YY.179 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src AA.BB.CC.DD

root@vm1 ~ # ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable

root@vm1 ~ # ping WW.XX.YY.179 
PING WW.XX.YY.179 (WW.XX.YY.179) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from WW.XX.YY.179 : icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.104 ms
*.... \o/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if separate Mac adresses are activated for your additional ip's try to use them with the vms.

This solution worked for me on pfsense

Answer (score 0):

```
auto  br0
iface br0 inet static
 address   WW.XX.YY.179 (the one from eth0)
 netmask   255.255.255.255 (the one from eth0)
 gateway   WW.XX.YY.160 (the one from eth0)
 bridge_ports eth0
 bridge_stp off
 bridge_fd 1
 bridge_hello 2
 bridge_maxage 12
```

I've had exactyl the same setup as you have and finally i did it by using the 'fully brdiged'-setup from hetzner. (Server is at hetzner too)

Maybe you're the same beginner as i'm so you have had fear of deleting eth0. I've had this fear too. But it works because Hetzner is using MAC-Routing, so your eth0 does not need to have a mac assigned by you.

Comment: "_MAC-Routing_" is an oxymoron. MAC is layer-2, but routing happens at layer-3. This must be some made-up marketing term.